# How to use uncertainties to weight residuals in a Savitzky-Golay filter.

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, filtering, data-fitting, uncertainty

Is there a way to **incorporate the uncertainties on my data set into the result of the Savitzky Golay fit**? Since I am not passing this information into the function, I asume that it is simply calcuating the 'best fit' via an unweighted least-squares process. I am currently working with data that has *non-uniform* uncertainty, and so the fit of the data could be improved by including the errors that I have for my main dataset.

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter#Weighting_the_data) for the Savitzky-Golay filter suggests how I might go about alter the process of calculating the coefficients of the fit, and I am staring at the code for [`scipy.signal.savgol_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html), but I cannot get my head around what I need to adjust so that this will do what I want it to.

Are there any ready-made weighted SG filters floating about? I find it hard to believe that no-one else has ever needed this tool in Python, but maybe I have missed something.

Comment: Did you end up solving a weighted Savitzky-Golay filter?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Python module: https://github.com/surhudm/savitzky_golay_with_errors

> This python script improves upon the traditional Savitzky-Golay filter
> by accounting for errors or covariance in the data. The inputs and
> arguments are all modelled after scipy.signal.savgol_filter

---

Matlab function `sgolayfilt` supports weights. Check the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sgolayfilt.html).